# How to get IP addresses of all interfaces on OS X using C

Tags: c, macos, ioctl

I am porting code from linux to OS X where I am getting these errors:

```
src/proxy_linux.c:784: error: 'SIOCGIFHWADDR' undeclared (first use in this function)
src/proxy_linux.c:784: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
src/proxy_linux.c:784: error: for each function it appears in.)
src/proxy_linux.c:788: error: 'struct ifreq' has no member named 'ifr_hwaddr'
```

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63) ) as development system.

SIOCGIFHWADDR is not supported on OS X and I am not able to find any credible source which can list out the ip addresses and MAC addresses of all interfaces. The only one I found on apple developer site uses "IOKit", which is also not backward compatible. Any help in this regard will be appreciated

Comment: Why you are not using `arp` for mac-ip retrieval?

Comment: @haccks I guess you are talking about linux commands, but I want some cue on sequence of statements/function calls through which I can retrieve info related to ip addr and all in C

Comment: You need to install the `arp` package on your mac. I am using it on my mac.  Install macport and then arp through it.

Answer (score 0):

If Sandbox or App Store is not involved you can parse the output of `ifconfig -a` yourself and extract the addresses. If so, well, you are out of luck as Apple won't allow this for privacy reasons.